# OneSignal Push Notification Sequence (order) is not correct

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am trying to setup OneSignal Push Notification for android/iOS for my app which has chat like feature. I want to deliver push notification to the user. I have integrated OneSignal SDK on my app and I am triggering Notification from my backend and I have observed that the sequence of the notification on the devices is not correct. Can someone suggest a workaround to get the notification in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Do not send push notifications immediately, schedule every notification with the same time you send it, and if two notifications have the same time, add one second to the second notification.

I've used this way and it works fine.